# pytorch how to set .requires_grad False

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient-descent

I want to set some of my model frozen. Following the official docs:

```python
with torch.no_grad():
    linear = nn.Linear(1, 1)
    linear.eval()
    print(linear.weight.requires_grad)
```

But it prints `True` instead of `False`. If I want to set the model in eval mode, what should I do?

Comment: [The documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#convnet-as-fixed-feature-extractor) has a simple example of fine-tuning that should help you.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

## requires_grad=False

If you want to freeze part of your model and train the rest, you can set `requires_grad` of the parameters you want to freeze to `False`.

For example, if you only want to keep the convolutional part of VGG16 fixed:

```
model = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
for param in model.features.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

By switching the `requires_grad` flags to `False`, no intermediate buffers will be saved, until the computation gets to some point where one of the inputs of the operation requires the gradient.

## torch.no_grad()

Using the context manager `torch.no_grad` is a different way to achieve that goal: in the `no_grad` context, all the results of the computations will have `requires_grad=False`, even if the inputs have `requires_grad=True`. Notice that you won't be able to backpropagate the gradient to layers before the `no_grad`. For example:

```
x = torch.randn(2, 2)
x.requires_grad = True

lin0 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
lin1 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
lin2 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
x1 = lin0(x)
with torch.no_grad():    
    x2 = lin1(x1)
x3 = lin2(x2)
x3.sum().backward()
print(lin0.weight.grad, lin1.weight.grad, lin2.weight.grad)
```

outputs:

```
(None, None, tensor([[-1.4481, -1.1789],
         [-1.4481, -1.1789]]))
```

Here `lin1.weight.requires_grad` was True, but the gradient wasn't computed because the oepration was done in the `no_grad` context.

## model.eval()

If your goal is not to finetune, but to set your model in inference mode, the most convenient way is to use the `torch.no_grad` context manager. In this case you also have to set your model to *evaluation* mode, this is achieved by calling `eval()` on the `nn.Module`, for example:

```
model = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
model.eval()
```

This operation sets the attribute `self.training` of the layers to `False`, in practice this will change the behavior of operations like `Dropout` or `BatchNorm` that must behave differently at training and test time.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Is there any efficiency difference between `torch.no_grad()` context manager and `t.requires_grad=False`, especially when it comes to memory efficiency? As you mentioned before, `t.requires_grad=False`, *no intermediate buffers will be saved*, will it be more efficient?

Comment: They are equivalent

Answer (score 6):

Here is the way;

```
linear = nn.Linear(1,1)

for param in linear.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

with torch.no_grad():
    linear.eval()
    print(linear.weight.requires_grad)
```

OUTPUT: False

Comment: this is in fact false: `linear.weight.requires_grad=True` and will remain `True` despite being in context manager `torch.no_grad()`. Pytorch will just ignore this vlaue during `torch.no_grad`, not change it.

Answer (score 6):

To complete @Salih_Karagoz's answer, you also have the [`torch.set_grad_enabled()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.set_grad_enabled) context (further documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#locally-disabling-gradient-computation)), which can be used to easily switch between train/eval modes:

```python
linear = nn.Linear(1,1)

is_train = False

for param in linear.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = is_train
with torch.set_grad_enabled(is_train):
    linear.eval()
    print(linear.weight.requires_grad)
```

Comment: This output is False.

Comment: Thanks @Tengerye, the answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Nice. The trick is to check that when you define a Linear layer, by default the parameters will have `requires_grad=True`, because we would like to learn, right?

```
l = nn.Linear(1, 1)
p = l.parameters()
for _ in p:
    print (_)
    
# Parameter containing:
# tensor([[-0.3258]], requires_grad=True)
# Parameter containing:
# tensor([0.6040], requires_grad=True)
```

The other construct,

```
with torch.no_grad():
```

Means you cannot learn in here.

So your code, just shows you are capable of learning, even though you are in `torch.no_grad()` where learning is forbidden.

```
with torch.no_grad():
    linear = nn.Linear(1, 1)
    linear.eval()
    print(linear.weight.requires_grad) #true
```

If you really plan to turn off `requires_grad` for the weight parameter, you can do it also with:

```
linear.weight.requires_grad_(False)
```

or

```
linear.weight.requires_grad = False
```

So your code may become like this:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    linear = nn.Linear(1, 1)
    linear.weight.requires_grad_(False)
    linear.eval()
    print(linear.weight.requires_grad)
```

If you plan to switch to `requires_grad` for all params in a module:

```
l = nn.Linear(1, 1)
for _ in l.parameters():
    _.requires_grad_(False)
    print(_)
```

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://github.com/MeiqiGuo/PytorchLearningNotes/blob/master/NoGrad.ipynb) may help.

In short words, I think a good way for this question could be:

```
linear = nn.Linear(1,1)

for param in linear.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

linear.eval()
print(linear.weight.requires_grad)
```

Comment: How is this different from / expanding over the older answers?

Comment: @dedObed I summarized some different use cases in the tutorial for giving a precise answer to this question. The accepted answer is very good. I included the .detach() which is quite related to this question in the tutorial.