# PyTorch torch.no_grad() versus requires_grad=False

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm following a [PyTorch tutorial](https://github.com/bentrevett/pytorch-sentiment-analysis/blob/master/6%20-%20Transformers%20for%20Sentiment%20Analysis.ipynb) which uses the BERT NLP model (feature extractor) from the Huggingface Transformers library. There are two pieces of interrelated code for gradient updates that I don't understand.

(1) `torch.no_grad()`

The tutorial has a class where the `forward()` function creates a `torch.no_grad()` block around a call to the BERT feature extractor, like this:

```py
bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

class BERTGRUSentiment(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, bert):
        super().__init__()
        self.bert = bert
        
    def forward(self, text):
        with torch.no_grad():
            embedded = self.bert(text)[0]
```

(2) `param.requires_grad = False`

There is another portion in the same tutorial where the BERT parameters are frozen.

```py
for name, param in model.named_parameters():                
    if name.startswith('bert'):
        param.requires_grad = False
```

**When would I need (1) and/or (2)?**

- If I want to train with a frozen BERT, would I need to enable both?
- If I want to train to let BERT be updated, would I need to disable both?

Additionaly, I ran all four combinations and found:

```
   with torch.no_grad   requires_grad = False  Parameters  Ran
   ------------------   ---------------------  ----------  ---
a. Yes                  Yes                      3M        Successfully
b. Yes                  No                     112M        Successfully
c. No                   Yes                      3M        Successfully
d. No                   No                     112M        CUDA out of memory
```

**Can someone please explain what's going on?** Why am I getting `CUDA out of memory` for (d) but not (b)? Both have 112M learnable parameters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an older discussion, which has changed slightly over the years (mainly due to the purpose of `with torch.no_grad()` as a pattern. An excellent answer that kind of answers your question as well can be found [on Stackoverflow already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748138/pytorch-how-to-set-requires-grad-false).
However, since the original question is vastly different, I'll refrain from marking as duplicate, especially due to the second part about the memory.

An initial explanation of `no_grad` is given [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/no-grad-vs-requires-grad/21272):

> `with torch.no_grad()` is a context manager and is used to prevent calculating gradients [...].

`requires_grad` on the other hand is used

> to freeze part of your model and train the rest [...].

Source again [the SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748138/pytorch-how-to-set-requires-grad-false).

Essentially, with `requires_grad` you are just disabling parts of a network, whereas `no_grad` will not store *any* gradients at all, since you're likely using it for inference and not training.
To analyze the behavior of your combinations of parameters, let us investigate what is happening:

- `a)` and `b)` do not store any gradients at all, which means that you have vastly more memory available to you, no matter the number of parameters, since you're not retaining them for a potential backward pass.
- `c)` has to store the forward pass for later backpropagation, however, only a limited number of parameter (3 million) are stored, which makes this still manageable.
- `d)`, however, needs to store the forward pass *for all 112 million* parameters, which causes you to run out of memory.

Comment: Thank you. When would (c) ever be used? (that is, gradients are collected but the parameters are frozen)

Comment: As long as you don't freeze *all* parameters of the network, it is possible to train only specific layers. For example, if you have a very large (but already pretrained) embedding layer, you can achieve much faster training times while potentially not sacrificing too much of your accuracy by simply freezing the embedding layer.

Comment: "Thank you. When would (c) ever be used? (that is, gradients are collected but the parameters are frozen)" -- Promptly, I can image only use cases where you want to backprob to the input e.g. for saliency analysis in images.

Comment: There are some works in NLP that utilize a (largely frozen) BERT model and fine-tune only minor portions, called [adapters](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.00751.pdf). I believe that approaches like this would classify as category (c).

Comment: But even using `with torch.no_grad (): #code` doesn't affect modules like `torch.nn.Conv2d`, which still has `requires_grad=True` inside the context manager.